# Google Sheets - OnEdit - Separate Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I am using the following code to automatically turn inputs in columns 1 and 4 of a sheet into a hyperlink. Whenever any range beyond 1 cell is pasted into the sheet only the first value will be hyperlinked into all cells in the range. Is there a way to get the cells within the range so I can have it check each cell for their individual value and column?

Thanks for any help!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  let range = e.range;
  let order = range.getValue()
  if (!( order === ''))
  {
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 || range.getColumn() == 4) {range.setValue("=hyperlink(\""+order+"\", \""+order+"\")");}
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a descriptive title as mentioned in [ask]

Comment: `getValue()` only returns the top  left range. Use `getValues()`

Comment: Yes you can use `e.range.columnStart, e.range.columnEnd,e.range.rowStart and e.range.rowEnd` which deternmins the entire range.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to tie it down to a single sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.rowStart > 1 && (e.range.columnStart == 1 || e.range.columnStart == 4) && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("flag1");
    e.range.setValue(`=hyperlink("${e.value}","${e.value}")`);
  }
}
```